# Summing a field from a core data result set

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to sum a field in a core data array. Essentially, I have a simple core data object with two properties a date and a number. There can be multiple records for the same date. The final output I am looking for is an array of dates and values. The dates represent individual distinct dates from my core data results and the values represent the sum of numbers for each value. In SQL I'd do the following:

SELECT eventDate, SUM(eventValue) FROM Events GROUP BY eventDate

But, I am not sure how to achieve a similar output with core data. Any ideas? Below is the code I have so far - it gets me all my managed objects (of class Event).

```
// handle the fetch request
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

// error declaration prior to fetch
NSError * error;

// try to fetch
NSArray *fetchedEvents = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSArray *distinctDates = [arrayOfEvents valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.eventDate"];
NSLog(@"%@", distinctDates);
```

Not sure if this is the right start. The distinctDates array above returns empty instead of returning an array of dates.

EDIT: 9/8
I've been able to figure out a way to do this by using a for loop that loads my fetchedEvents array into another custom array where I aggregate my counts by date and store the results in an array of dictionary objects. This works, but I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on a better approach then:

- loading my entire subset of data
- aggregating my data into an array of objects based on some grouping (date in this case)
- displaying this

Is there something analogous to "group by" for core data?